# Ubuntu apt failed to install package, unable to purge

Tags: ubuntu, package, apt

Unable to locate and delete failed package, because there are post installation scripts that get triggered.

Package is nvidia-l4t-kernel

I found a Nvidia forum post suggesting to remove the failed package here:
[NVIDIA Forum](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/error-procedure-for-bootloader-update-failed-when-executing-sudo-apt-get-upgrade/188602/8)

I'm on Jetson Nano (Ubuntu 18.04), trying to to upgrade jetpack-sdk-461 to jetpack-sdk-463
One of the packages that comes in from apt update / apt upgrade needs to be removed, according to above linked forum post.

That is where the problem lies. I found the packages in `/var/lib/dpkg/info` and used `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq nvidia-l4t-kernel` which seemingly removed the packages as they are not inside the directory any longer. However, from `sudo apt list | grep nvidia-l4t-kernel` it still shows up and attempting to `sudo apt upgrade` shows: `3 not fully installed or removed.`

That is referring to these packages:

```
nvidia-l4t-kernel/stable 4.9.299-tegra-32.7.3-20221122092935 arm64
nvidia-l4t-kernel-dtbs/stable,now 4.9.299-tegra-32.7.3-20221122092935 arm64 [residual-config]
nvidia-l4t-kernel-headers/stable,now 4.9.299-tegra-32.7.3-20221122092935 arm64 [residual-config]
```

which show when using `sudo apt list | grep nvidia-l4t-kernel`

Here the entire output of above command:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  tensorrt
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up nvidia-l4t-bootloader (32.7.3-20221122092935) ...
3448-300-0000--1--jetson-nano-devkit-
Starting bootloader post-install procedure.
ERROR. Procedure for bootloader update FAILED.
Cannot install package. Exiting...
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-l4t-bootloader (--configure):
 installed nvidia-l4t-bootloader package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up nvidia-l4t-xusb-firmware (32.7.3-20221122092935) ...
3448-300-0000--1--jetson-nano-devkit-
Starting xusb firmware post-install procedure.
ERROR. Procedure for xusb firmware update FAILED.
Cannot install package. Exiting...
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-l4t-xusb-firmware (--configure):
 installed nvidia-l4t-xusb-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-l4t-initrd:
 nvidia-l4t-initrd depends on nvidia-l4t-xusb-firmware (= 32.7.3-20221122092935); however:
  Package nvidia-l4t-xusb-firmware is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-l4t-initrd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-l4t-bootloader
 nvidia-l4t-xusb-firmware
 nvidia-l4t-initrd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I would highly appreciate if anyone here could kindly point me into the right direction.
Been working on this problem all morning already :-/

Thanks to anyone taking the time to help!

Comment: Anyone here can tell me where the post-script is getting triggered from,please?